# Компонент WebBrowser .NET Core - отсутствует метод Print

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, webbrowser, core

В проекте WPF .NET Core использую компонент WebBrowser. Отсутствует метод Print, а для WinForms он есть

Как тогда печатать? Похожего метода найти не могу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Спасибо

Comment: Какая версия .NET Core?

Comment: `WebBrowser` - уже официально вымерший динозавр. Microsoft уже похоронила Internet Explorer. Так что можно уже начинать от него избавляться, потому что дальше будет только хуже. `CefSharp` или молодой и сыроватый `WebView2` на базе новомодного Chromium-Edge можете попробовать.

Comment: Версия .Net Core - 3.1